# How to update multiple items in a Directus flow, with different values for each item?

Tags: directus

I've created a simple Directus flow:

1. Trigger is `items.update` for collection `invoice`
2. Operation is `update` data in the same `invoice` collection

As a payload I have (note the `array`):

```
[
  {
    "id": 16,
    "temp": 16
  }
]
```

This sound strange but it's only for testing purposes. I want to update multiple items for the same trigger, each item with it's own data. In the future, that array will be computed by another operation.

The above payload won't work. Field `temp` isn't set for that invoice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can update multiple items through flows. You can use patch option in the flows. For more details, please check the following link which has example.

https://github.com/directus/directus/discussions/16258#discussioncomment-7653287